# Suggest framework for external rule storage

Tags: java, javascript, search, architecture, decision-tree

There is a **situation**:

I've got 2 .xlsx files:

**1. With bussines data**

for example:

```
 -----------------------------------------
| Column_A | Column_B| Column_C | Result |
 -----------------------------------------
| test     | 562.03  | test2    |        |
------------------------------------------
```

**2. With bussiness rules**

for example:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Column_A       | Column_B    | Column_C                        | Result |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EQUALS:test    | GREATER:100  | EQUALS:test2 & NOTEQUALS:test  |   A    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EQUALS:test11  | GREATER:500  | EQUALS:test11 & NOTEQUALS:test |   B    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With condition in each cell.
One row contains list of these conditions and composes one rule. 
All rules will be processed iteratively. But of course, I think, it would be better to construct some 'decision tree' or 'classification flow-chart'.

So, my task is: to store these conditions functionality (methods like **EQUALS**, **GREATER**, **NOTEQUALS**) in some external file or some other resource. To have a possibility to change it without compilation into java bytecode. To have a dynamic solution, not to hard code in java methods.

I found **DROOLS** http://drools.jboss.org/ as a whay that can work with such cases. But maybe there are another frameworks that can work with such issues?

JavaScript, DynamicSQL, DB solution is not suitable.